# Nodejs wait user to give input?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for looping program continuously, but the problem looks like the program run without waiting for user make an input

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

const questions = [{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'name',
  message: "What's your name"
}];

do {
  inquirer.prompt(questions).then(answers => {
    console.log(`Hi, ${answers['name']}`);
  });
} while (true);
```

Comment: An infinite loop blocks the single thread that your code runs. So it will also block any async tasks like the `then` handler.

Comment: So many, so many people, all day long, asking "How do I do this with `then()`? I can't get the result of my HTTP call! I can't pause the execution of my code! I can't do this, I can't do that" and the answer to all these questions, all day long, is "Drop then() and use async/await". Next question in the queue : "I'm using then() but the result of my HTTP call is undefined, why?"

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to wait for user input is to use async/await. First you need to wrap block into self executing async function and then use await to get user response.

```js
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

const questions = [{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'name',
  message: "What's your name"
}];

(async () => {
    do {
        const answers = await inquirer.prompt(questions);
        console.log(`Hi, ${answers['name']}`);
    } while (true);
})();
```